# PHPpgAdmin: How delete rows without using SQL

Tags: database, postgresql, phppgadmin

In [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) I can delete rows without using SQL.

Is there a way to do this in [phpPgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpPgAdmin) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

phpPgAdmin (ppa) gives ability to edit/delete a row only when it founds an unique index in the table (or in requested fields for a query) and the value for the indexed col is not null.

Without unique index (or PK), ppa could not determine a WHERE clause to select the only row you want to edit/drop.

Comment: ALTER TABLE your_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (your_id_field1);

Be aware that the key fields must not be null...

Comment: I've just seen your other question about PK, there's a more complete answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, just select the table, click "browse" and then click "delete" (in the column "actions") for every row you want to delete.

Comment: I don't see column actions. Are you sure you are talking about PHPpgAdmin and not PHPmyAdmin ?

Comment: I see column actions but In my PHPpgAdmin there is NOT a column actions. Maybe is it disabled ? thanks ^_^

Comment: In some table of your phppgadmin there isn't column actions.

Comment: @FrankHeikens When there is no PK or Unique index then you don't see actions column.